# ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm newbee in oracle and
I try to change `varchar(50)` to `250`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CEQ_OWNER.TYPE_REC_PARAE2
AS OBJECT    
(
    ...
    BONETAT_DESC  VARCHAR2(250),
    ... 
)
/
```

I get ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are other types or tables that depend on the type you want to change. If it's a dependent type, then you can use the FORCE option to change the type.

If it's a table that directly or indirectly uses the type, then you will need to create a new type and a new table, migrate all the data, and finally drop and rename tables and types.

See this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjmng.htm#CHDBAEHJ) for some further information.

Comment: Is there a way to find all type usages?

Comment: Yes, there is a table that lists all dependencies (i.e. usages): DBA_DEPENDENCIES.

Comment: While i can compile my type without problems, my colleague has this same error. She tried in TOAD and SQL Developer. We cannot figure out why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You are probably locking each other. Close all SQL tools (yours and your colleague's), start a single tool and try again.

Comment: Above link is dead. Here is an actual link to Oracles PL/SQL Language Reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375

Answer (score 21):

I was looking everywhere for the syntax also, but was having a hard time finding the documentation. From the page that Codo linked... notice that the `FORCE` is between the object name and `as object`

```
create or replace type ceq_owner.type_rec_parae2 FORCE as object    
(
  ...
  BONETAT_DESC  VARCHAR2(250),
  ... 
)
/
```

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
drop type your_type force;
```

Comment: also: 'drop function my_demo_proc;'  In case you had your old types called from a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some dependency for the Object you are trying to Modify or Drop.

If you want to skip this first drop the dependant Object and try to DROP or MODIFY

Like in the below Screenshot

[image]

Regards,
Arul

Comment: What does your answer ad to th answers that were posted years ago?

Comment: If you want to experiment with formatting you can use https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/