# Why can't we drop a referenced Type unlike other schema objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

When a `Type` which is having dependents is tried to drop or replace, oracle throws below error. Unlike for the other schema objects (like procedures) where you drop an objects then it gets dropped and the dependent objects get `invalid`. My two questions are

1) Why is `Type`so special that it prevents drop/replace when it has dependents.

2) What logic takes separates the above behavior for `Type`.

create

```
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674807/ora-02303-cannot-drop-or-replace-a-type-with-type-or-table-dependents)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am not asking why did I get the error, I know the `Type ` is referenced. My question clearly states it.

Answer (score 3):

> "Why is Type so special "

There are two differences between Types and Procedures.

1. Sub-types have an absolute dependency on their super-type. If a stored procedure has a dependency on a function and we delete that function the procedure is invalidated. But we can make the procedure valid simply by editing the code so it doesn't use the function. Whereas if we drop the super-type the sub-type is permanently invalidated; we cannot edit it to remove its dependence on the super-type, because the super-type defines it. Simply, the sub-type is inoperable until we re-create the super-type.
2. We can use a Type to declare database tables and table columns. Those are structures with persistent state: we can't invalidate a table column like a stored procedure, because of the data. If we drop a Type which is used by a database table we lose the data held in the Type structure.

There is syntax to drop a Type with dependencies without hurling ORA-02303:

```
drop type my_type force;
```

This renders all the sub-types invalid, and - more drastically - sets any dependent table columns as `unused` and invalidates any dependent tables. An `unused` table column is effectively dropped; its data is inaccessible. To recover an unused column (or invalidated table) requires [a tablespace point-in-time recovery on an auxilliary instance](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5320382600346145195), which is not a trivial undertaking. (That it is so easy to unwittingly render data irretrievable is one reason why object-relational tables are not a good idea.)