# Why do we need nested table columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I came across nested tables and objects last week working with Oracle DB. I know how to create nested table and how to store values store values, but I am struggling to see the big picture. Why do we need nested tables? Why can't we create two normal tables and link them with a foreign key? Isn't it easier to create two tables?

Thanks

Comment: Just my opinion: yes, it is easier & simpler to have two tables. Nested tables - that's a *nice* feature (as if Oracle wanted to say "look what we can do!"), but I've never used them apart from educational purposes. Someone else might have a different experience and opinion, which would be perfectly OK.

Comment: There's likely to be some subjectivity answering this since you've used 'Easier' but subvalued / multivalued columns pre-date SQL - Pick / Universe for example. TL;DR is joins aren't free. An example usage would be invoice and line items in a system where all invoice data would always need to retrieved and where querying line items in isolation isn't required. Nested tables have some commonality with NoSql document databases.

Comment: @StuartLC - *joins aren't free*. True but RDBMS products have engines optimised for joining data. Also, denormalised data structures aren't free. Not only is the syntax clunkier than SQL with straightforward tables but they impose limits on how we can use the data (which you acknowledge in your caveat, *"where querying line items in isolation isn't require"*: querying line items in isolation is always required).

Comment: Types and nested tables are very useful as programmatic objects, especially for exchanging data between PL/SQL procedures and for pipelined functions. Almost every application I've worked on for the last twenty years has used them for that. But there is little need to declare columns as types or nested tables: [in fact it can be quite dangerous, as I discuss in this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003433/146325). Obviously there are use cases for so-called unstructured data such as LOBs, XML and JSON, but these are generally edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

In general you are right. It is easier to create an additional table and link it with base table. In fact Oracle is doing that, it create a (hidden) table and adds a (hidden) column to your base table in order to link them.

I used them occasionally when I have a big application, let's say hundreds of tables and this application has to common provide import/export functions. In such case the table design has to be aligned with structure or external data (e.g. an XML-File). Then it can be easier to use nested table in order to have more generic import/export procedures.